# Posting video from iOS to Facebook App's page via generic HTTP POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, post, video

I am trying to post/upload local video from iPhone/iPad to Facebook app, but the result is universally `Unsupported post request`.

Facebook user under which I am signed in has access to app and permissions to post pictures/video. I am setting parameters `title`, `description` and `source` (the latter required by Graph API) and also using valid access token in `access_token`. All parameters and page ID are checked, all valid, none is `nil`. Video block is ~1M of `NSData`. I tried using all API versions from `2.2` to `2.5` with the same result.

The code is using generic HTTP request running synchronously.

HTTP request body is created by the following function:

```
- (NSData *)createBodyWithBoundary:(NSString *)boundary
                    parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                         vData:(NSData *)videoData
                         vFile:(NSString *)videoFile
{
    NSMutableData *httpBody = [NSMutableData data];

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%@\r\n\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add params (all params are strings)

    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];

    // add video data

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", videoFile] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: video/quicktime\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:videoData];
    [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    return httpBody;
}
```

Then, it is executed by the following block:

```
NSDictionary* params = @{@"title"        : [self SHA1Digest:objectID],
                       @"description"  : videoDescription,
                       @"access_token" : accessToken};
NSString* boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
NSMutableURLRequest *basicRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.5/%@/videos", Facebook_Page_ID]]];
[basicRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *httpBody = [self createBodyWithBoundary:boundary
                                     parameters:params
                                          vData:videoData
                                          vFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov",[self SHA1Digest:objectID]]];

basicRequest.HTTPBody = httpBody;

NSURLResponse* basicResponse = nil;
NSError* basicConnectionError = nil;
NSData* basicData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:basicRequest
                                          returningResponse:&basicResponse
                                                      error:&basicConnectionError];

if (basicConnectionError) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", basicConnectionError);
}

NSString *basicResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:basicData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The result of execution is always the same:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170627b40> { URL: https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.5/1420425574917397/videos } { status code: 400, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "no-store";
"Content-Length" = 211;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Fri, 16 Oct 2015 20:21:20 GMT";
Expires = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
"Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api\"";
"facebook-api-version" = "v2.5";
"x-fb-debug" = "A/ZxL2wA3zgj4fjZUxMNABl0VVf4lsviLmXzT0+5wdIMglNjOg02tEBM0uoUMTV/tLlqIz/IL4Ls/eKaOYTDsA==";
"x-fb-rev" = 1993425;
"x-fb-stats-contexts" = ": api, : V6";
"x-fb-trace-id" = EtCc6pDDQrD;
} }
```

Comment: Where is `Facebook_Page_ID` supposed to come from? Is that your actual code, or is that supposed to be a placeholder for a constant value?

Comment: It's a constant value. One value in PROD, another - in DEV.

Comment: The code was using App ID instead of App Page ID. Using the correct page ID solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code was using App ID instead of App Page ID. Using the correct page ID solved the problem